# Symfony Automatism in URL reWrite

Tags: php, symfony, url, url-rewriting, root

The name of my web site is "vg"
The dev url is : "http://localhost/vg/web/app_dev.php/"
The prefix definition set in the vg\app\config\routig.yml is : "/gallery"

So the question is : how to add automatically the prefix (gallery) to the url given by a user or process if the url is just "http://localhost/vg/web/app_dev.php/"

(.../gallery/ is the equivalent of traditional index page.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In `routing.yml` you could add a simple redirect:

```
# redirecting the root
root:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /gallery
        permanent: true
```

Reference: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/redirect_in_config.html

If the prefix (here `gallery`) is a configured value, do the redirection with a controller method:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="index")
 */
public function indexAction(): Response
{
    $urlPrefix = 'gallery'; // get this value from wherever appropriate, e.g.
                            // a service, class constant, a value from parameters.yml

    return $this->redirectToRoute('some_route', [
        'prefix' => $urlPrefix
    ]);
}
```

Suppose you want the prefix-value in code, then it shouldn't be a configured route prefix, but a proper router parameter:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{prefix}", name="some_route")
 *
 * @return Http\Response
 */
public function someAction($prefix): Response
{
    // do things with $prefix

    return $this->render('view.html.twig');
}
```

both actions can be in the same controller.

Comment: just the word "gallery" is set behavior on the prefix tag in the vg\app\config\routig.yml file.
I don't want to set "/gallery" but I want to use the content of this "prefix" parameter
So , there is a representative "meta data" for "prefixe" that could be used at the right place on the tag "path" in your previous answer ?
like : 
path: {prefixe} // is an example

Comment: @PhilippeGODEFROY Ah ok, so the real prefix is unknown but will be available as some kind of config parameter?

Comment: I did it.
so I have : 
# src/VG/paintBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

vg_paint_index:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: VGpaintBundle:Paints:index
        path: /gallery
        permanent: true

When I ask the URL : http://localhost/vg/web/app_dev.php
I obtain : ' No route found for "GET /" '

Comment: Ok for the function but sorry , in which script should I write it ? 
In my bundle-controler ?

And how retrieve the value (/gallery) set on the prefix tag in the  vg\app\config\routig.yml file

Comment: Yeah, it needs to be in a controller. Personally I would put it in the most *general-purpose* controller of your bundle.

Comment: Regarding your second question, if you want to use the value (your prefix) in code, it shouldn't be a prefix. Make it a proper route parameter.

Comment: That's what I feared
I have already the indexAction function (that build my page)
So I fully lost.
I so sorry but I'm aged of 2 days old in Symfony

Comment: @PhilippeGODEFROY I added another example of how you would use the prefix in code. Remember that you need to remove the prefix tag in `routing.yml` for this to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found. And I want sincerely to thak you.

1. In the `vg\app\config\routing.yml` file

```
    vg_paint:
        resource: '@VGpaintBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml'
        prefix:   /gallery

    root:
        path: /
        defaults:
            _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
            path: /gallery
            permanent: true
```

---

2. In the `# src/VG/paintBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` file

```
    vg_paint_home:
        path: /
        defaults:
            _controller: VGpaintBundle:Paints:index
            page: 0
            requirements:
                page: \d*

    vg_paint_index:
        path: /{page}
        defaults:
            _controller: VGpaintBundle:Paints:index
            page: 0
            requirements:
                page: \d*

    vg_paint_view:
        path: /paints/{id}
        defaults:
            _controller: VGpaintBundle:Paints:view
            id: 0
            requirements:
                id: \d+
```

And now if I call http://localhost/vg/web/app_dev.php (with or without `/` at the end) the "gallery" word comes at the end of this URL
@+